# Are some ARIA attributes added by simple_form automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, wai-aria, section508

And if so, how do I stop them from being added?

I'm adjusting a web app to be 508 compliant, and it seems as though (at least for radio buttons and checkboxes) that an 'aria-labelledby' attribute is being added automatically. Is there a way for me to stop this from happening, maybe altering the config, or using a custom wrapper? I've looked through the documentation, and couldn't find much. Here is the input (in HAML) that I start out with:

```
= f.input :is_round_trip, as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_tag: nil, label: t(:trip), collection: [[t(:round_trip), 1], [t(:one_way), 0]], checked: (@trip_proxy.is_round_trip ? "1" : "0")
```

And this is what gets compiled:

```
<label for="trip_proxy_is_round_trip_1" name="trip_proxy[is_round_trip]">
  <input aria-labelledby="is_round_trip_label" checked="checked" class="radio_buttons optional" id="trip_proxy_is_round_trip_1" name="trip_proxy[is_round_trip]" type="radio" value="1">Round trip
</label>
```

Comment: What version of SimpleForm are you using?

Comment: Right now, I'm on 3.1.0.rc2

Comment: The only ARIA attributes that simple_form adds that I can find is `aria-required`. See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=aria

Comment: is it possible you have some javascript that is adding the `aria-labelledby`?

Comment: @ckundo: I have made an approach into this direction, see https://github.com/jmuheim/base/blob/features/accessibility/app/assets/javascripts/form_errors_accessibilizer.coffee.